# How to move users to a new mailchimp list as part of a campaign?

Tags: mailchimp

I am using mailchimp to manage invitations for the beta launch of a web site. I have a list for people that have requested an invitation and would like to move them to another list when sending a campaign that includes the invitation so we can track who has been sent an invite.

How can I configure mailchimp to move people from one list to another list? Or is there a better way to manage the list in order to avoid sending an invitation to the same person more than once?

Comment: As note... I'm asking this question here because while we are using the mailchimp API for other functionality, I believe this should be possible to achieve directly within the mailchimp site, so I thought this would be the best SE site to ask on.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a data field (Merge field) in your current list that can be used to identify the people who want to be in the beta you can just segment the list and send it to those people.

Also you cant have duplication of emails as Mailchimp checks and updates the existing user.

Hope this helps if not then I can explain some  more once at work (and I can then see mailchimp)

Comment: I should have clarified on the duplicates... I want to make sure that people sent an invitation are not sent another one. So I need some way to mark that the invitation was sent to a user. At the moment we have two separate lists, but I'm not sure that is the best approach.

Comment: If your able to segment the people your sending to from the one list you could use the segment option of "opened" (a particular campaign) + the original segmentation you did

Comment: That's the kind of thing I'm looking for, but I want 'sent' instead of 'opened' which isn't an option and 'any campaign' which is an option... halfway there.

Comment: Would date added be of any help? If you know the date/time you sent the last mail that could work for you

Comment: Date added won't work because the invites aren't always sent chronologically.

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer from support at MailChimp. It looks like it has to be done manually as there is no way to segment on whether someone has been sent a campaign -- only if they have opened it.

Here's the blurb from MailChimp...

> We checked out the segmenting options and
>   it looks like there's an option for date added is after a certain
>   campaign was sent, but there isn't one for who received the last
>   campaign (just who opened / clicked in the list campaign). What might
>   work instead is adding a group in the list that would denote if
>   someone was sent the invite (this could be marked off manually in the list by
>   someone with account access). Then the list could be segmented based
>   on that field for later sends (who is or isn't in that group to get
>   the new campaign that's going out).